# How to rig a shirt with buttons so that the buttons follow the mesh of the shirt

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

I didn't address this in a while because I was busy with something else, but now it has cycled back into my schedule. 
Right now I have a shirt modeled and bones set in place. It's already technically rigged, but the only issue is the buttons.
[image]

I'm not entirely sure how to go about connecting them to the shirt's deformations.
I tried to combine them and the shirt into one object, but because of the shirt's modifiers, (Solidify and subsurf, which I don't want to apply yet), the buttons become extremely deformed.
I've tried to match the weight painting intensity where a button is at in correspondence with the shirt, but that doesn't seem to work, maybe it has to do with the specifics of where the button is?
[image]

Is there a way to make the buttons follow the shirt's deformations without deforming the mesh vertices of the button?
I know that if I probably apply the modifiers on the shirt and combine it with the buttons, it would be okay, but I'm not okay with doing that just yet with the shirt.

[image]

I rigged the shirt by deleting all vertex groups, assigning empty groups to the mesh from the armature, and then assigned automatic groups in the weight paint menu.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Parent to 3 Vertices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Parent to 3 Vertices**

[image]

[image]

Original Flat Plane at the Parenting time.  This may not matter.  Image Above.

Note the Parent Setting.  The beformation of lightweight fabric or clothes maybe very different than the moving human body.

[image]

Shapley beformation with Shape Keys.  Note the buttons follow location and normal of the three vertices.  Blender determined the three vertices for the Blender User convenience.

[image]

The Parent Menu. Parent Plane Child Button. Image above.

Comment: Mhh, the post was way better after Ben's edit. Why rolling it back?

Answer (score 13):

You may do it using vertex and object parenting.
[image]

Select the vertex where you want to place the button and snap the cursor to it. In *Object Mode* add an *Empty* there.
[image]

Now select the *Empty*, then the mesh and enter *Edit Mode*. Select three vertices around the button and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->*Make Vertex Parent*. Finally parent the button object to an *Empty*. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->*Object (Keep Transform)*).
[image]

Comment: Just realized you don't need empties to make it work good. Just parent each button to three vertices (as atomicbezierslinger did in his answer).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking up how to do this in 2022, like I did today, I should note that when I tried this the first time, it failed.

[image]

My **parent object** is deformed by an armature. However, the **child object** that was parented to the **parent object** vertices (tri) would move opposite of the **parent object vertices** being deformed by said armature.

**To fix this**:

- Select **child object** and **Set Origin To Geometry** *(Shift Ctrl Alt C)*.
- Parent **child object** to **vertices** on **parent object**.

The order of this is important.

[image]

At some point I had applied **Location, Rotation and Scale** which caused the issue. Easy to miss.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Despite reading and watching the previous examples I was quite confused. After playing, and respecting what I could of the previous answers, this is my attempt to simplify.

Consider "button" and "shirt" to be examples of anything you want to have a "button on shirt" relationship.

1. Make sure origin of button's origin is set to the place where you want the button to connect to the shirt.
2. Select button
3. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select shirt
4. Go to *Edit Mode*
5. Select 3 vertices in the area the button should attach to. Try to pick vertices that work together to create a "flat" surface for the button to sit on.
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and parent to vertices
7. Go out of *Edit Mode* and move the shirt to test connection