# How to attach mesh object to another mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, hair

I'm still new to blender and I've been having trouble attaching meshes to another mesh. For example, I'm trying to attach this hairpiece accessory to this hair mesh and I can't quite seem to get it to stick. 
[image]
[image]
The best I can do is have it joined together with the hair but it doesn't follow the armature when I pose it around like it wasn't even attached.

Parenting it to a hair bone also messes it up. I got no clue.

Is there a proper way to do this? Any help would be great!

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87357/how-to-rig-a-shirt-with-buttons-so-that-the-buttons-follow-the-mesh-of-the-shirt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Vertex triangle" Parent object option, which will make your accessory follow the movement of the trhee vertices of the parent mesh (Hair) nearest to the child.

So select accessory, shift select hair, press Ctrl P and choose "vertex triangle".

After selecting the hair, if you tab into edit mode you can choose three vertices to act as leaders of the movement.

[image]